# GeoLocation from gpsd

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, gps, geolocation, gpsd

The [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) program lets linux users cleanly organize their GPS peripheral data, such that a command line program like `cgps` or a graphical one like `xgps` can read the data, and write to a socket, like `/var/run/gpsd.sock`.

There's a [nice tutorial](http://blog.retep.org/2012/06/18/getting-gps-to-work-on-a-raspberry-pi/) on the net for rigging a raspberry pi to use this data. This is all well and good, but how can I integrate this data in firefox or chromium, as the [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) API? Is there a specific build process I might need? For instance, setting a `./configure` flag or something? Is there a way to integrate this data in a prebuilt version of either browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firefox** on Linux supports gpsd - it was [added in Firefox 4](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492328), [removed in Firefox 23](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866893) and [added back in Firefox 50](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250922).

However, it still needs to be enabled during build, with `--enable-gpsd` (which seems [not to be the case yet in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1783202)) and in the configuration, by following these steps:

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Create a new string preference, name `geo.location.use_gpsd` value `true`

Prior to Firefox 23, you had to:

2. Create a new string preference, name `geo.gpsd.host.ipaddr` value `localhost`
3. Create a new boolean value, name `geo.gpsd.logging.enabled` value `true`

**Google Chrome** had gpds support [added in November 2011](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=109736&view=revision) and [removed in October 2013](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=227104&view=revision). It looks like [hardware GPS support is not a priority](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=350519). If this was handled in Chrome OS, it might be possible to use the same mechanism, but I don't see support there either.

Someone [built an extension which attempts to provide support](https://github.com/micolous/gpsd-chrome-polyfill) in recent versions, requiring to install a script system-side.

Answer (score 3):

**Firefox** on linux [used to support gpsd](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492328#c26).

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Create a new string preference, name `geo.gpsd.host.ipaddr` value `localhost`
3. Create a new boolean value, name `geo.gpsd.logging.enabled` value `true`

However, it seems that the [gpsd support has been removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866893)

**Chromium** seems to have had gpsd support in the past, but I can't find anything about it now. It looks like [hardware gps support is not a priority](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=350519). If this was handled in ChromeOS, it might be possible to use the same mechanism, but I don't see support there either.

**In both cases**, it should be possible to write an extension to fake the GPS coordinates, which could read from your real GPS.

Comment: With emphasis: Mozilla bug [866893 - Remove support for **multiple** geolocation providers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866893) was  RESOLVED FIXED in Firefox 23. [1250922 - Add gpsd location provider](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250922) was  RESOLVED FIXED in Firefox 50.

Comment: It seems in Firefox 50+ you have to set `geo.location.use_gpsd` to `true` in `about:config` to activate the `gpsd` location provider: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/76b04196acce